# how can I load multiple csv files in a directory to neo4j with a single load

Tags: csv, neo4j, load

I have a folder with 620 file I need to load all to neo4j with one load command is this is possible

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate all the files in that folder into a single file (e.g., `cat * >all_data.csv`) and load that single file.

Answer (score 1):

The import-tool supports reading from multiple CSV source files, even using a regex pattern to select them. See http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/#import-tool